# foreach and for javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

For each 'a'-tag (.arrow-class), I want to add an anchor tag of a .jump-class, but I'm stuck using the foreach and for functions. This is what I have, but the 'a'-tag gets the last value in the array:

```
var arr = [];

$(".jump").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    arr.push(id);
});

var arrayLength = arr.length;

$(".arrow").each(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        $(this).attr("href", arr[i]);
    }
});
```

EDIT: ANSWER:

```
var arr = [];

$(".jump").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    arr.push(id);
});

var arrayLength = arr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
    $(".arrow").each(function (i) {
            $(this).attr("href", '#' + arr[i]);
    });                 
}
```

Comment: Why are you "stuck" using `for`/`foreach`?

Comment: don't use an inner loop on the 2nd one, you're not iterating the arrows ever. use the params supplied to forEach to provide "i"

Comment: @EthanBrown: I think they mean they're "stuck" as in having trouble using them, not that they *must* use them.

Comment: `$(this).attr("href", arr[i]);` --- this statement is run multiple times for every `.arrow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is going to loop more times than you need

```
$(".arrow").each(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        $(this).attr("href", arr[i]);
    }
});
```

Instead try

```
$(".arrow").each(function (i,arrow) {

        $(arrow).attr("href", arr[i]);

});
```

Comment: I think not, but ill check

Comment: Thanks! Works with $(".arrow").each(function (i) :)